# How can I remove the explanation error from my form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a contact form with Bootstrap, and I found a code snippet on the net. The code is working fine, except the error messages that it shows.

My contact form should be in several languages, so I do not want to show explanation error details if a user provided incorrect information. Here you can see my form: http://158.69.62.110/bs/

How can I get rid of those error messages? Showing red border and cross icon would be sufficient.

How can this form supports different languages?

Comment: Can you just remove the `message` property from each of the `notEmpty` validators?

Comment: I did, it does not work. Still showing "This value is not valid".

Comment: did you try leaving the message empty like this: notEmpty: {
                        message: ''
                    }

Comment: Yeah exactly, and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a callback method which you can put in your input tag and enter your custom error message.

Take a look at http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/ also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882152/5549391) answer on stackoverflow.

Hope this helps a little.